# Comparing two data tables on different tabs in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to Macros and VBA in Excel, so I need some guidance on how to solve my current issue.

The end goal of my project is to have a macro compare two sets of data organized into rows and columns (We'll say table A is the source data, and table B is based off of user input). Each row in table B should correspond to a row in table A, but they could be out of order, or there could be incorrect entries in table B.

My thought is that for the first row in each table, the macro would compare each cell left to right:

```
If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(2, 1) = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(2, 1) Then
    If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(2, 2) = Seets("sheet2").Cells(2, 2)
```

Ect, ect.

My problem comes in when the Cell in table B does not match Table A.

First, I would want it to check B row 1 against the next row in A, and keep going throughout table A until it finds a "complete match" with all five columns of the row matching.

I've been trying to do this with Else if and For/Next staements

```
For row= 2 to 10
'if statements go here
     Else If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(2, 1) <> Sheets("sheet2").Cells(2, 1)
Next row
```

I may be completely misunderstanding the syntax here, but I have yet to produce a situation where if the criteria is not met, it goes to the next row.

If no complete match is found, the last cell in table B row 1 that couldn't be  matched should be highlighted.

*Then* regardless of whether a match was found or not, we would move to table B row 2, and start the whole process over.

So, I have the logic worked out (I think), where the comparison ifs would be inside a loop (or something) that would cycle through table A row by row. Then that whole process would be in another loop (or something) that would cycle through Table B.

At the end of the process, there would either be no highlighted cells showing that all entered data is correct, or cells would be highlighted showing data that do no match.

I am fairly certain that the cycling through table B is not the issue. Rather, I'm having difficulty getting the Macro to move to the next table A row if something doesn't match.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate on anything.

Thanks!

Comment: You could simplify the process by concatenating each row and comparing that before finding which cell is not a match.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow1 As Long, Lastrow2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Str1 As String, Str2 As String

    'Find the last row of sheet 1
    Lastrow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last row of sheet 2
    Lastrow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To Lastrow1
        'Let us assume that table has 3 columns. Merge 3 columns' values and create a string for each line
        Str1 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value & "_" & Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value & "_" & Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value

        For j = 2 To Lastrow2
            'Let us assume that table has 3 columns. Merge 3 columns' values and create a string for each line
            Str2 = Sheet2.Cells(j, 1).Value & "_" & Sheet2.Cells(j, 2).Value & "_" & Sheet2.Cells(j, 3).Value

            'If both strings match a message box will appear
            If Str1 = Str2 Then
                MsgBox "Line " & i & " in table A match with line " & j & " in table B!"
                Exit For
            End If

        Next j

    Next i

End Sub
```

Sheet 1 structure:

[image]

Sheet 2 structure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! Your coding example concatenates the fields which is definitely something I was considering doing, I just don't know if I'll be able to individually point out not matching cell contents with this method, which is why I was leading towards the nested ifs.

When I was trying out your code to make sure I understood the syntax, it seemed like the message box wasn't triggering? I tried a few different fixes, and it seems like the Lastrow1 and Lastrow2 variables are the culprits. I've also had trouble getting these to work on my own, any idea what's happening?

Comment: The message box will pop up as soon as Str1 (Sheet1 values from column A, B, C) is the same with Str2 (Sheet2 values from column A, B, C). Lastrows, seems to be correct.

Comment: Interesting. Whenever I try to step through the code it goes directly from "For i = 2 To Lastrow1" to "End Sub". I'm trying this out in a new workbook that I haven't renamed. I don't see any references to a specific workbook name, could that be it? I've also kept the default tab names, if that matters.

Comment: What are the values of Lastrow1  & Lastrow2?